# Bubble Sort not outputting in correct order (float)

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, bubble-sort

can't seem to find anything about this as I can't really word it correctly. Basically when I bubbleSort my list it from negatives up to the lowest negative and then reads in the positives, lets say it's [1.6397, -2.0215, -0.4933, , -3.4167] it will sort as [-0.4933, -2.0215, -3.4167, 1.6397]

by algorithm is

```
    def bubbleSort(array):
        n=len(array)
         for i in range(n):
            for j in range(0, n-i-1):
                while array[j]>array[j+1]:
                    array[j], array[j+1] = array[j+1], array[j]
```

I want this to read like
[-3.4167, -2.0215, -0.4933, 1.6397]

thanks in advance

additional:

```
    example=[]
    with open('ex.txt') as f:
        for l in f:
            l=l.strip()
            example.append(l)

    examplesearch=input('select array to sort')
    if (examplesearch == ex1):
    bubbleSort(example)
    print(example)
```

Comment: As a side note, why are you using `while` and not `if` ?

Comment: When I call this function with `[1.6397, -2.0215, -0.4933, -3.4167]` I get the output you expect - `[-3.4167, -2.0215, -0.4933, 1.6397]`.

Comment: oops, yeah it is 'if' on my code i just rushed that example, my bad

Comment: When I run this code, it sorts the array correctly.  Show us the code that calls this function and prints the result.

Comment: hmm strange, my numbers are imported from a txt file, the function is being called to sort the file into numeric order. I'll have a quick play around and see if it something in my loop.

Comment: _my numbers are imported from a txt file_ Are you converting the numbers to actual float values, or are they still strings?

Comment: it gives me an error cannot convert string to float if i try to convert, i believe i have been sorting the list as string

Answer (score 1):

Since you are reading from a file the inputted numbers are strings, thus Python uses string comparison (as evident by the result you are getting).

You have to convert to `float` first:

```
example = []
with open('ex.txt') as f:
    for l in f:
        l = float(l.strip())
        example.append(l)
```

BWT, you don't need to pre-create the list:

```
with open('ex.txt') as f:
    # 'if number' will handle potential empty line at the end of the file
    output = [float(number.strip()) for number in f if number]
```

Comment: yeah, this is what i originally tried except i get a valueerror 'could not convert string to float', hence why i believed it to be a problem with the algorithm

Comment: @JoeBenson then you probably have an empty line at the end of the file. See the updated code.

Comment: still same error message, very odd.The file has an empty line and other lines with           " ' ' ", maybe these lines are the problem with converting all strings into floats